# Elasticsearch plugin to classify documents

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin

Is there an elasticsearch plugin out there that would allow me to classify the documents that I enter in an index?

The best solution for me would be a classifications of all the most recurrent terms (/ concepts) displayed in a sort of tags cloud that the user can navigate.

Is there a way to achieve this? Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: Why not index your terms/tags and then use aggregation queries?

Comment: @ryanlutgen Thanks for your answer. Can you please elaborate on that? (I also added a bounty). Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The basic idea is to use a [`terms` aggregations](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html), which will yield one bucket per term.

```
POST /_search
{
    "aggs" : {
        "genres" : {
            "terms" : { "field" : "genre" }
        }
    }
}
```

The response you'll get will be ordered by decreasing amount of term occurrences:

```
{
    ...

    "aggregations" : {
        "genres" : {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0, 
            "sum_other_doc_count": 0, 
            "buckets" : [ 
                {
                    "key" : "jazz",
                    "doc_count" : 10
                },
                {
                    "key" : "rock",
                    "doc_count" : 5
                },
                {
                    "key" : "electronic",
                    "doc_count" : 2
                },
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

If you're using Kibana, you can directly create a [tag cloud](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/tagcloud-chart.html) visualization based on those terms.

Comment: Didn't try yet (it's actually not for me but for a coworker). Thanks for your answer

Comment: Sad you lost rep in the process ;-)